# Blender added extra bones on the final tip of each original bone

Tags: animation, mesh, export, bones, .fbx

As per subject, tried to export an fbx (just the mesh and rig: I avoided to extract animation for now) but, on reimporting it into Blender, I see it haves an extra bone to each final tip, and the root bone is stuck inside the upper bone.
[image]

Comment: In the import dialog there is an option "*Armature > [X] Ignore Leaf Bones*". Enabling this should fix the extra bones.

Comment: I suspected it could have been this, and I saved a copy unchecked: but I stll get the sticked root and now the wings bones (the ones in lighter grey) have the tip misplaced from their areas.